# Styling label css using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, drupal-7

I have a radio group which is coming dynamically to my page. I was able to successfully disable any radio using php, but I want to add css property of text-decoration: line through on the disabled radio label. This is the code :

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-example-pane-time-slot-1">
    <input type="radio" id="edit-example-pane-time-slot-1-11" name="example_pane[time_slot_1]" value="11" class="form-radio">
    <label class="option" for="edit-example-pane-time-slot-1-11">11 - 12 pm </label>
</div>
```

How is it possible using jquery ? My jquery code is this :

```
if ($('#edit-example-pane-time-slot-1-11').attr('disabled',true))
{
    $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
}
```

and its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just css

[CSS adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

[CSS :disabled pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled)

```
.form-radio:disabled + .option {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lzvs48hm/)

Comment: Ok. But how will I target 1 radio from the group as I have mentioned its a radio group not a single radio button

Comment: Thank you ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ this was the best solution to my little problem. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking

```
if ($('#edit-example-pane-time-slot-1-11').attr('disabled')===true))
    {$(this).siblings('label').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');}
```

Or to just disable it, you should use `.attr('disabled','disabled')`. Seems you mixed these two.

PS: Please read difference between == and === in JavaScript.

Comment: I know the difference === is identical isnt it ?

Comment: there is a difference. Also you input tag does not seem to be formulated properly.

Comment: Actually it is disabled already, I just want to add the css property to label after checking that is the radio disabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to add css for it.

```
$(this).siblings('label').css('text-decoration','line-through');
```